# Migrate repeating sections in Infopath to PowerApps in Office 365

Tags: office-365, infopath, powerapps-forms

I have migrated a site to Office 365 and there was a list that was using Infopath.

The Infopath form uses repeating sections and it is not mapped to any column. Is there a way to recreate the form in Plumsail or Powerapps?

I am able to create repeating sections in PowerApps/Plumsail and it works fine for new items, but I am not sure how to map the repeating section to make it work for older items. Is there a way to map the repeating sections so that it works for items that already have entries in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using an infopath form that was connected to a form library, this means that the data was being stored as XML. As such, it had access to xml features, like repeating sections and such. There is no equivalent in poweapps. Options:

1. Redesign the form to store data in multiple lists instead of a single list. So if the form was for customers and the repeating section was for orders, create those two lists, and connect the power app to both.
2. Redesign the form and store the mutiple rows as multiple lines in a multi-line text field (yes, this option is limiting. If the repeating section has a single field, then this could work well. Otherwise, see the first option)
3. Same idea, but instead of sharepoint lists, use either the CDS or a sql database instead of sharepoint. Pros include better performance. Cons include that licensing to use these features requires giant piles of money.

Sorry, there's really no migration path from InfoPath to Power Apps.

Or, perhaps I misunderstood your question. If you already have created a power app that uses multiple lists for the repeating sections, then all you need is a little powershell to connect to the existing forms, which again are just xml files, and then write that data to your new lists.

Comment: Thanks Mike
So when I redesign the form with PowerApps and have a separate list for repeating items, to make it work for the existing old items, I need to migrate the data from XML, to the list that is storing the repeating section entries. Hope I got your suggestion right

Comment: That's exactly what I was suggesting. And again, there's no migration path from MS, so moving the content from the xml files to the new lists is either a manual process involving a lot of copy and pasting, or some PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will try this out and let you know. Hopefully, this should work